How to rotate / scale around a reference point in flutter/dart?
I have a CustomPaint which I pass a object, derived from CustomPainter. In its paint() method I get a Canvas to which I draw an image.
Question: Now I need a rotation with a reference point - so not rotating around the origin but e.g. Offset(100,200). How can this be done?
In other languages, I moved the reference point to the origin, performed the rotation and afterwards moved everything back:

In Flutter it seems, that the rotation is still performed around the top-left point of the image - even if it is moved away from the origin.
My Code:
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(painter: SomePainter());
  }
}

class SomePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    canvas.translate(-100, -200);
    // rotate by 30° counterclockwise
    canvas.rotate(-30 / 180 * pi);
    canvas.translate(100, 200);  // might need some sin/cos to rotate this vector before

    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
  }
}

In a second step, I would like to perform a scaling on a reference point. This does not work with the strategy from above as well...

Update: I just experimented with the Transform widget, which does what I want - but how to do this within the paint() method and the Canvas?
  Transform(
    // My image is 800x400, thus 100,200 is 12.5% / 50% of the image
    alignment: Alignment(0.125 * 2 - 1, 0.50 * 2 - 1),
    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-30 / 180 * pi),
    child: CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter()),
  ),


its better ti use one Canvas.transform instead, a handy method for getting the Matrix4 is composeMatrix and here it is used in canvas.transform - you can run this gist to see how it works

and when you run it, it shoudlnt be surprise that it is used for drawing the car traveling from Hamburg to Munich ;-)
